# Drawing a straight line on camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas

I am using Camera Api in my app.I want to draw Straight line on camera preview and mark some pixel values on it I am using frame layout to show camera preview.What I have to do..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) they have samples similar to what you want.

Comment: I dont want openCV its just to see weather the position is correct

Comment: Well, then, as the other answer suggests, you have a SurfaceView, right? You can draw on the surface view as they do in SDK Lunar Landler sample. You can have a camera preview callback set up so you are getting the preview pixels and determine somehow what to draw from them http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [custom camera activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)

Comment: Then you can draw your requirements on CameraPreview Surface View

Comment: How.? That is what I asked? is there any example